# what is difference between installing sqlite3 and making .sqlite file?

Tags: database, sqlite, apollo

I'm trying to learn apollo and following the docs and this documentation using sqlite to show how to connect local database to server.
i didn't install sqlite3 but the .sqlite file is in given source.
Even though it was out of the lecture but i got curious how this works though i didn't install it.
i have searched to find why it works and what is difference between these but i couldn't find it so i reached here to ask question about what are the differences and what is better to use.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is a library extensively used in different programming languages like python, javascript, php etc. This library is made using C-language which implements a small, fast, self-contained, high-reliability, full-featured, SQL database engine. ".sqlite" is a database file which contains all the data stored. This file can be made by executing some code based on syntax of that particular language. For you to work on SQLite, you need to have installed it on your local machine.